# Quadratic Bezier Curve: Calculate Tangent

Tags: bezier

I have a quadratic bezier curve and I want to calculate the slope of the tangent in a given point. For example, let it be the middlepoint of the quadratic bezier curve, therefore t=0.5 (please see the link below for a picture of this). I've calculated the first derivative of the formula for the quadratic bezier curve; however I get 400 as value for the slope, though it should be 0. Maybe I'm using the first derivative in a wrong way? I know I could also calculate the tangents using trigonometric functions; however I'd like to do it using the first derivative, shouldn't this be possible? Thanks for any hint!

For clarification / please note: I'm interested in a general way to get the slope in a arbitrary given point on a quadratic bezier curve, not only to get the tangent in the start- and end point.

A picture of my problem including the text above:
http://cid-0432ee4cfe9c26a0.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/%c3%96ffentlich/Quadratic%20Bezier%20Curve.pdf

Thank you very much for any hint!

Comment: The link appears to be dead. It'd be nice if you could translate your formula into the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your formula for `B'(t)`, evaluated at `t=1/2`, we get

```
B'(1/2) = -P0 + P2
```

From the look of your graph, P0 = (0,0) and P2 = (400,0). So

```
B'(1/2) = (400,0).
```

This is the "velocity" of a point traveling along B(t) at t=1/2.

(400,0) is a horizontal vector, with magnitude 400.

So all is as it should be. Since B'(t) is horizontal, it does have "slope" 0.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, but the "t" is always erased from the equition 2t*(0)+400 because it's multiplied with 0. so the slope in every point would be 0, which isn't true!?

Comment: @stefan: It is true that the x-component of B'(t) is always 400, but this is not true of the y-component. Try y0=0, y1=100, y2=0 for the y-components of P0, P1, P2, and computing y'(t). You should find y'(t) does depend on t.

Comment: @Since slope is rise over run, the slope is not x'(t), but rather y'(t)/x'(t).

Comment: Thanks, got it why B'(t) is 400. And y'(t)/x'(t) works fine. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[Derivatives of a Bézier Curve](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-der.html)